# a mismatch exception in java

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the Salary input, I entered 1500.99 as input, then the compiler tells me that there is a mismatch exception

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 import static java.lang.System.*;

 public class input {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner reader=new Scanner(in);

    System.out.println("hello world ");
    System.out.println("enter a name ");
    String name=reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("name: "+name);
    System.out.println("enter the age ");
    int age=reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("age: "+age);
    System.out.println("enter the salary ");
    double Salary=reader.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("salary "+Salary);
  }
 }
```

Comment: I guess it is a decimal separator issue : 1500,99 may be a double whereas 1500.99 is not

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine with the scenario you've given, I think you are using a "," as your decimal

Use a "." instead of a ","

A comma would be seen as String input and you are requesting double input

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using dot as decimal separator. Decimal separator depends on your system input/language settings. Your code is fine when you type 1500,99 instead 1500.99.

Or if you want to recognize dots (like 1500.99), change this line:

```
double Salary=reader.nextDouble();
```

to this:

```
double Salary = Double.parseDouble(reader.nextLine());
```

Answer (score -2):

Problem was in you Scanner just replace this Scanner like with this

```
Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: That wouldn't cause a mismatch exception, that would cause a "can't find symbol: in" error. Their second import imports `in` anyways.